# EC2 Instance not working despite of status "running"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My EC2 instance stopped working suddenly. The status of the instance in the EC2 Console is shown as *running*. Nevertheless I can't connect via SSH. I have even rebooted the instance but with no effect.

I am not an AWS expert. Can you advise what I should do?

Comment: what is the problem you are having.
Are you not able to ssh or program which is installed on ec2 is not working

Comment: The machine was down but after a couple of Reboots it is up. I do not know how it went down. Not sure how to figure it out. Any logs?

Comment: If you are not able to ssh then you should check your security group policy which is attached to the ec2. It might possible your ip address is not in the white list of the security group policy. then you have to add incoming traffic with 22 port and your ip address in attached security group

Comment: for the logging system Use AWS Cloud Trail. Please see the documentation: AWS CloudTrail. You can get complete history of api calls to your account

Comment: Has *your* IP address changed? What Security Group ingress rules are configured for the EC2 instance that you are trying to SSH to?

Comment: @jarmod IP is not changed at all, no changes.

Comment: Run through the connectivity troubleshooting at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html